# Enter-PSSession in a script doesn't do what I expect - it executes on local machine instead of remote

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

The  "CD" command in script below executes on local machine instead of remote. What's wrong?

```
Add-PSSnapin Windows.ServerBackup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
set-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value 81.xxx.xx.xx
$WBResult = $WBSummary.LastBackupResultHR
$WBErrorMsg = $WBJob.ErrorDescription + "`n" + $WBSummary.DetailedMessage
$User = "administrator"
$File = "C:\Users\jsapsford\Desktop\Password.txt"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString)

If ($WBResult -eq 0) { $WBResult = "Successful"}
Else {$WBResult = "Failed"}

if ($WBResult -eq "Succesful") {$text = 'document.write("Succesful");'}
Else {$text = 'document.write("Failed");'}

$serverconnection = New-PSSession -ComputerName 81.xxx.xx.xx -Credential $cred
Enter-PSSession -Session $serverconnection

cd C:\website\                                      
$text | Out-File 'company.txt'
```

Basically what Im trying to do is connect to a server using remote powershell, it is then meant to cd to C:\website and create a file called company.txt but what is happening is it is executing the `cd C:\website` and `$text | Out-File 'company.txt'` on the local machine im running the script from instead of the remote machine. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried to use the UNC path \\remotecomputer\website?

Comment: just tried that and it appears to just put it into a shared folder i have called website which isn't the website folder i want it to go in.

Comment: I've never tried enter-pssession in a script like that.  Usually you'd `Invoke-Command -Session ... -ScriptBlock { ... }` and do your work in the block.  You can do `$using:text | Out-File c:\website\company.txt` inside the block.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Worked a treat thank you very much

Comment: Posted as answer with a bit more context.  Glad it worked.

Comment: While we're on the topic, consider saving a credential with `export-clixml`, and importing it again with `import-clixml` instead of a plain text password file. This will encrypt your password at rest (on disk) more securely.

Comment: @xjacksssss, please accept the answer when you have a moment so that other folks will know you've found a solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enter-PSSession` is typically for interactive command line use.  For scripted remote calls, there are two main `PowerShell` remoting patterns with `Invoke-Command`.

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName ... -ScriptBlock { ... }`
is good for one-off calls. Note the `-computername`. Using this argument pattern suffers the cost of setting up and tearing down the connection and authentication with each call. It's convenient in that you don't need to remember to clean anything up.

Switching to `New-PSSession` as in your original question gives a more persistent connection that can be re-used over and over, specifying `-Session` instead of the `ComputerName`. For good resource hygiene, you'll want to remove the session after you're done. I usually use a `try/finally` pattern.

In either case, then do your work in the `ScriptBlock`. You can do `$using:text | Out-File c:\website\company.txt` inside the block.  The `using` scope qualifier allows you to reference variables from your calling context.

Answer (score 0):

sorry this is going to be a bit of a rubbish answer but i ended up scrapping the whole thing and starting again, instead of creating the variable then carrying that across etc. it now creates the text file on the local machine then transfers it to the server via FTP much easier way to do it. If you want me to upload the code I'm now using i will but until interest is shown ill leave it for now. Thanks all for our help

Comment: While you've solved your problem with a new approach, the answer to your original question does have an answer.  Without any answer accepted, people may continue to revisit this and spend time suggesting other alternatives that aren't needed.